# Can gnus handle "maildir" format mail files with ".eml" extension?

Tags: microsoft-windows, search, gnus, email

I've been using "gnus" for reading/writing mail in MS Windows, but to make
Windows recognize mail file, I want to add ".eml" extension to each numbered
mail in "maildir" format.

Is there any way to attach extension to gnus mails with "nnmaildir" backend?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Standard maildir filenames in the `cur` directory end with `:2,`, followed by a list of flags (`R` for replied, `S` for read, etc, (see [the spec](https://cr.yp.to/proto/maildir.html)).  I'm not sure how that works for Windows; can you have colons in filenames?  Regardless, it looks like you'll have to do a lot of surgery to `lisp/gnus/nnmaildir.el` to make it retain `.eml` as a suffix.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, as long as nnmaildir persists with maildir spec, it would be difficult to attach .eml suffix at the end...
So the question would be, what would be the best practice to use "gnus" on Windows Emacs, so that mail files would be properly recognized by Windows OS, and searchable with Windows Search API?